# AND in more than one value (Excel)

Tags: worksheet-function

I'm trying to filter a column by using AND(), but, differently from IF(), it gives only one answer for the whole interval.

```
=AND(SQRT((A!$B$2:$B$658-Sheet1!J651)^2+(A!$C$2:$C$658-Sheet1!K651)^2)>0,SQRT((A!$B$2:$B$658-Sheet1!J651)^2+(A!$C$2:$C$658-Sheet1!K651)^2)<10)
```

How can I have a answer for each line?

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help), then [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1776732/edit) your question accordingly providing more context and details. It's a good idea to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour), at least the Asking and Answering -sections in the Help Center and some older questions with [accepted answers](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) to learn how the site works.

Comment: AND returns a single answer and not an array.  You need to multiply(*) the two boolean tests together to get an array of 1 and 0.

Comment: Further to [Scott Craner](https://superuser.com/questions/1776732/and-in-more-than-one-value-excel#comment2771474_1776732) if trying to filter using two conditions: `FILTER(B2:B658,(condition 1)*(condition 2))`